# Ping a database or send a ping with info

Tags: console

I wanted to ask a probably silly question:

Is there a way to ping a database from a website?

Let me explain myself, the webpage of my uni is down. Well, not the web page, the users database. When you try to access the page, there is no problem, the server responds and you get the page, it's when you try to login that it stops working.

So I was wondering if there is a way to ping the database or ping the page with the user info so it "uses" the database. Of course if you ping the site, you obtain a response, there is no problem, but I find reloading the page every now and then a little bit boring.

When I say ping I mean by console, I don't pretend to write a script or anything.

I know it's not a vital question and it's probably silly since I don't have access to the database, but hey, I'm here to learn.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"probably silly since I don't have access to the database" - only in exceptional cases would the database server be accessible from the public web. The 'usual' architecture has the web server as the accessible face of the site, with everything else securely hidden behind a firewall. Even where the database server is run on the same server as the web server, access is usually restricted to processes running on the server.

In any case, even if the database server was accessible, you'd need to know something about it to do anything useful. A network `PING` will establish whether the server is alive, but won't tell you anything about the state of the database. To do more you'd probably need to log in with a suitable database client - I can't see any self-respecting sysadmin allowing users access to a datbase server at that level!